# Redirect to Struts 2 action class after user completes PayPal purchase

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, paypal, struts2

I am using the PayPal Sandbox in my Struts 2 web project.

I have a `payment-method.jsp` that contains the PayPal form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">     
    <!-- other stuff -->

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost:8080/mysite/payment-method.jsp">

    <!-- payment button -->                     
</form>
```

I have specified the `return` value as `payment`.

I have defined the action in my `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="payment" class="com.mypackage.action.PaymentAction">
    <result>/transaction-result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But it's returning to the PayPal Sandbox homepage.

*How do I redirect to an action (instead of an actual page) after the user completes their transaction in PayPal?*

(The `cancel_return` works by the way.)

Comment: You want to redirect to `jsp ` or another action ?

Comment: On `return`, I want to redirect to an action.

Comment: Then in that case you need to change the `<action name="payment" class="ph.watchy.action.PaymentAction">
    <result>/transaction-result.jsp</result>
    <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
</action>` to `<action name="payment" class="ph.watchy.action.PaymentAction">
    <result>/transaction-result.jsp</result>
    <result name="index" type="redirect">ActionName to which you want redirect</result>
</action>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/

first read this document and give your action url in return url in your paypal account.

And set Auto Return to on.

no, you cant check on localhost if u have live url then check on live.

Comment: Hi, my web project is not yet live and the above url worked. I'm accepting this answer because _"give your action url in return url in your paypal account"_ was the clue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect to action then

you change this

```
 <action name="payment" class="ph.watchy.action.PaymentAction">
<result>/transaction-result.jsp</result>
<result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
```

to

```
  <action name="payment" class="ph.watchy.action.PaymentAction">
   <result>/transaction-result.jsp</result>
   <result name="index" type="redirect">ActionToberedireected</result>
  </action>
```

Give action instead of `index.jsp` to which you want to redirect ..